# Reading from Excel to SQL - wrong column type

Tags: sql-server, excel, t-sql, type-conversion, openrowset

I have such procedure to read data from many excel files:

```
IF EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM sys.objects
            WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'GetDataFromFiles') AND type IN ( N'P', N'PC' ) ) 
    DROP PROCEDURE GetDataFromFiles
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE GetDataFromFiles (
    @Months VARCHAR(50),
    @Excels_path VARCHAR(200),
    @File_name VARCHAR(15),
    @Workbook_name VARCHAR(50),
    @Table_name VARCHAR(15),
    @First_run INT)
AS
    DECLARE @Query VARCHAR(5000)

    IF(@First_run = 1)
        SET @Query = 'SELECT * INTO '+@Table_name
    ELSE 
        SET @Query = 'INSERT INTO '+@Table_name+' SELECT * '

    SET @Query +='
            FROM openrowset(''Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'', 
                ''Excel 12.0 Xml;Database='+@Excels_path+'\'+@File_name+'.xlsx;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1'', 
                ''SELECT * FROM ['+@Workbook_name+'$]'')'
    --Print @Query
    EXEC (@Query)
GO
```

My problem is when there is `First_run=1` the columns which have null value are taking as float. On next step (in next excel file) it can be string in these columns and then I have an error: `Error converting data type nvarchar to float.`. How can I avoid getting this error?
I have tried make another #temp table which each of columns (which could have null value) could be converted to varchar, but I think it is too complicated, because I made this procedure to simplify my query.

Comment: If the column in Excel is supposed to be an integer, why should it have a string value? Or did you mean an **empty** string?

Comment: As you can see the error says that query wants to convert varchar to float, so in columns, which I am talking about, are strings. Of course there, where are columns with int - it's okey when first insert has null value in column, but it's not okey when in first step there is a `NULL` and in the second (in other file) there is `abc` value in this column. In excel can't be such thing as `empty string`, right?

Comment: A cell with an empty value would count as an empty string I believe. And I also believe a NULL value should be expressed that way and not with an `'NULL'` string value. Also if memory serves right, the provider guess the column type of the Excel file from the first data row. So if you have a string (not empty?) in your first row the provider will assume a NVarChar type for the column.

Comment: Let's say one more time: when in first FILE are only null values in column for example `Description` and it should be strings, and when in next file there are strings, the error comes up, because in first step `openrowset` function read column as float. So in my case, when first file has null value in columns, they will be taking as floats, not string. If you want, please check it on your computer importing example two excel files.

Comment: A quick google led me here: http://blog.concentra.co.uk/2013/05/15/why-ssis-always-gets-excel-data-types-wrong-and-how-to-fix-it/. Unfortunately, if `IMEX=1` doesn't work, apparently you have to change things in registry...

Comment: Got it, I was reading that backward (like the destination column was float but source data was string). This is really strange because the IMEX=1 should ensure that data is imported as string according to https://www.connectionstrings.com/ace-oledb-12-0/treating-data-as-text/

Comment: @HoneyBadger It didn't help. I am reading different files, so when whole column has `NULL` values the `NULL` value it still be taking in first step.

Comment: Write a dynamic query to alter the table and change all the columns to varchar after the first run.   It's going to get complicated.   There is no simple way to do what you want.